# How to make a recursive code from this iterative code? (drawing tree graph)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a question about drawing tree graph. I use my iterative code to build a tree graph. Here it is.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(*der={1,3,4,2};*)
der = Input["Add a lot of points in each level, enclosed in curly braces.
(contoh = {1,3,4,2}) : "]
awal = 1;
agab = {};
tekan = 1;
For[k = 1, k <= Count[der, _Integer] - 1, k++,
  If[k == 1, mbiyen = 0, tekan = der[[k - 1]]];
  For[l = 1, l <= tekan, l++,
   For[j = 1, j <= der[[k]], j++,
     a[j + mbiyen] = 
      Table[j + mbiyen \[UndirectedEdge] i, {i, awal + 1, 
        awal + der[[k + 1]]}];
     agab = agab \[Union] a[j + mbiyen];
     awal = awal + der[[k + 1]];
     If[j == der[[k]], mbiyen = j + mbiyen];
     ];
   ];
  ];
agab
Graph[agab, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

Now, I use`{1,3,4,2}` into input form. Then the graph looks like this
[image: 1,3,4,2 tree graph]

But I have a problem when the levels are more than 4. It still left the vertex.
Can anyone fix this code? Or maybe change into recursive mode?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what kind of graph you try to create? I thought I understood it but the [output of `{2,3,4}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G5mNb.png) got me thinking.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd,<br>That is **tree graph**. On my example above, {1,3,4,2} : The first level is just 1 vertex, the 2nd level are 3 vertex, the 3rd level are 4 vertex. So I don't use {2,3,4}, but the first must be 1. Then, my code can walk no more than 4 levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give a short and readable implementation which uses the function `nextLevel` as its core. It's only three small lines which need to be understood:

```
nextLevel[{v_, _}, n_] := Block[{c = Last[v] + 1, ids, i = 1},
   ids = Range[c, c + Length[v]*n - 1];
   {ids, Table[UndirectedEdge[k, ids[[i++]]], {k, v}, {n}]}
];
```

The function `nextLevel` takes a list of graph vertices from one level `v` and a number of children which the vertices will have. In your example, this would give in the second level the list `{2,3,4}` as vertices and `4` because they split each into 4 new children. 
First, the function calculates `c` which is the id of the next node (after vertex 4 comes 5). Then it creates a list of all children in the next level. This would be the list `{5,6,...,16}`. The `Table` call creates the edges by connecting the current vertices with the correct child vertices.
As return value, we give back `ids` which is the list of child vertices required for the iteration in the next round and all edges from this level of the tree to the next.

That's it. The only thing that's left is to use `FoldList` to iterate over your list of tree depths:

```
makeTree[depths : {_Integer ..}] := 
 Flatten[FoldList[nextLevel, {{1}, {}}, depths][[All, 2]]]

Graph[makeTree[{4, 3, 2}], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Side note 1: If you wonder about the argument right of the `v_` in `nextLevel[{v_, _}, n_]`, this is where we *remember* our resulting edges. With `Fold` (or `FoldList`) we either can do it that way or we could use `Sow` and `Reap` to send the resulting edges where we can collect them.

Side note 2: Creating a tree-structure and labeling it in [pre-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) is easier and can be done in fun ways. One of them is a simple call to `ArrayReshape` with your depth-list:

```
Block[{count = 1}, ArrayReshape[{}, {4, 3, 2}] /. List | 0 :> count++] // TreeForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want. Not recursive (no real need).

```
    maketree[spec_] := 
     Flatten[Function[edg, MapThread[Thread[#1  \[UndirectedEdge]  #2] &, 
            {First@edg, Partition[Last@edg, Length@Last@edg/Length@First@edg]}]] /@ 
       Partition[FoldList[Range[Max[#] + 1, Max[#] + 1 + Length@#*#2 - 1] &, {spec[[1]]}, 
                          Rest@spec], 2, 1]]


graph=maketree[{1, 2, 2, 2, 3}];

Graph[graph, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]